# CSS - transform: rotateX animation not working on mobile browsers (even with -webkit-)

Tags: html, ios, css, animation, cross-browser

I got an animation on my [page](http://tobiasgla.us/), where a word is rotating. Thats done with this CSS keyframe animation using `transform:rotateX(90deg)`:

```
.words .active{
  display:inline-block;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 55%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 55%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 55%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 55%;
  transform-origin: 50% 55%;
  -webkit-animation:ueli 3s forwards;
  -moz-animation:ueli 3s forwards;
  -ms-animation:ueli 3s forwards;
  -o-animation:ueli 3s forwards;
  animation:ueli 3s forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes ueli{
  0%{
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(-90deg);
  }
  50%{
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(0deg);
    opacity:1;
  }
  100%{
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(90deg);
    opacity:0;
  }
}
@keyframes ueli{
  0%{
    opacity:0;
    transform:rotateX(-90deg);
  }
  50%{
    transform:rotateX(0deg);
    opacity:1;
  }
  100%{
    transform:rotateX(90deg);
    opacity:0;
  }
}
```

I've read on another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28731030/css-animation-not-working-on-mobile-chrome-or-safari-ios), that on iOS every browser uses webkit, because they are based on uiwebview. So I added webkit to my animation. 
But it's still not working on mobile devices.
On [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=transform) I tested, if the transform property even is supported on mobile and yes, it is. So that can't be the problem I guess. Anyone knows how I can fix that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

*Possible solution #1*

Try using this:

```
-webkit-animation-name: ueli;
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

instead of

```
  -webkit-animation:ueli 3s forwards;
```

This **could** fix your problem.

---

*Possible solution #2*

Try using a different name for each browser keyframe.

```
-webkit-animation: webkit-ueli 3s forwards;
 animation:ueli 3s forwards;
```

And

```
  @-webkit-keyframes webkit-ueli{
  @keyframes ueli{
```

---

*Possible solution #3*

**"Note: This property must be used together with the transform property."**

Try adding a transform outside the keyframe.
[W3schools ref](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it didn't fix my problem :/

Comment: Edited my answer. Hope the second approach fixes your problem.

Comment: That doesn't work aswell, but a nice thought :) You could check it out on the page I mentioned in my question. I changed the code according to your answer there.

Comment: Last try. Then i'm out of inspiration :)

Comment: I'm sorry. The animation just don't want to work. But you get an upvote for your effort :)

Comment: Thankyou hehe, i'm sorry none of the solutions helped you. If something else pops in my mind i'll let you know :) It works on iPad, and i'm a Samsung user so testing is not possible in my case.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

In your style.css `-webkit-keyframes` is written wrong

```
@-webkit-keyframes ueli {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotateX(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotateX(90deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes ueli {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

change it to

```
@-webkit-keyframes ueli {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes ueli {
  0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotateX(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotateX(90deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

it works for me on IOS [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yfgry31c/3/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I changed it that way, but it still doesn't seem to work :/ Check it out on [my website](http://tobiasgla.us). Do you know what the problem is? Is something else in JS or CSS affecting its behaviour?

Comment: in which browser did u check.it works fine on safari v6

Comment: I tested it on Safari (idk which version (i got the newest firmware)) and on Chrome (v58.0.3029.83)

Comment: just want to ask is it working correctly on chrome and on safari is anything displayed(items) initially

Comment: No, there is just nothing. But I think, the text is in the "end-state" so rotated by -90deg, because it IS there (div got the size as if there was text).

Comment: Thanks alot for your help :)  I cleared my cache, etc. -> nothing happened. 
Then I went eating some pizza and when I came back and refreshed, it worked. I'm not sure, but I guess pizza is the solution to everything.

Comment: You are welcome..:).Finally caught the culprit,i was thinking what went wrong after modifying -webkit-keyframes because when i tested initially it didn't work but after writing it correctly its fine on my device.It was little confusing at first because in your question you wrote it correctly but not in your css.Cheers bro..:)